# Como pegar valor de uma String antes de um caracter Especial

Tags: java, string

Olá, bom dia. Estou com uma pequena dúvida, como posso pegar o valor de uma String antes de algum caracter especial. Por exemplo, Clinica Antonio S/S. Gostaria de pegar apenas o Clinica Antonio S, o que vem depois da barra não precisa ser pego. 
Alguém pode ajudar? Valeu

Comment: O que acontece com a frase 'Eu não sei! É legal!'? Sua pergunta está vaga, descreva melhor com mais exemplos!

Comment: O que eu quero é percorrer uma String até achar um caractere especial. Exemplo Clinica Antonio S/S, quero percorrer até a "/" e pegar apenas o que tem antes da /, que no caso é Clinica Antonio S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//String a ser analisada
String Str = new String("Clinica Antonio S/S");
//Posição do caracter na string
int pos = Str.indexOf("/");
//Substring iniciando em 0 até posição do caracter especial
System.out.println(Str.substring(0, pos) );
```

**[Veja um exemplo Ideone](http://ideone.com/TC4VU6)**

Comment: neste caso só funcionaria para o caracter '/'.

Comment: @RenaroSantos, sim é um exemplo simples sobre o problema apresentado, e creio que a linguagem é Java e não JavaScript

Comment: Muito obrigado, com base na sua resposta consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado a todos que reapoderam também.

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar a função `StringTokenizer` contida em `java.lang.Object`

Por exemplo:

```
public class Demonstracao{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      // Cria um StringTokenizer passando como parâmetro a sua string
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Ola/Mundo");

      // Verifica o próximo token
      System.out.println("Proximo token: " + st.nextToken("/"));
      System.out.println("Proximo token: " + st.nextToken("/"));
   }    
}
```

Neste caso o output seria:

```
Proximo token: Ola
Proximo token: Mundo
```

Comment: Mostrar um exemplo de como usar deixará sua resposta melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das maneiras de se fazer, em Javascript é a seguinte:

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
     var str = "E ai mané.Tudo bem?";
     var n = str.search(/á|é|í|ó|ú|(|)/); ///coloque aqui todos os caracteres especiais
     var a = str.substr(0,n); /// var a = 'E ai man'
 }
</script>
```

Em outras linguagens de programação, é só seguir a mesma lógica.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Clinica Antonio S/S"

s.split(/[^\w\s]]/,1)
```